# Is it a good idea to use Google AMP for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, amp

Is it considered a good idea to use Google [AMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Mobile_Pages) for Magento 2 in 2021? I am looking for general advice. Some consider AMP as something good, but some people may say it has failed.

Why is it a good idea or why not? I am looking for the reasoning why.

Comment: By AMP, you mean on Google AMP?

Comment: @djm.im yes, indeed.